# How to check if an event target value exist in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my rails app, I would like to use Jquery to check if a event target value from a select dropdown exist in an array. If it does, I hide a div and vice versa.
In my controller, I derive the array

```
def new
  @number = Course.where(course_type: "physical")
  @new_number = @number.ids
end
```

In my views, I have this jquery code

```
<script>
 var number = <%= @new_number %>;
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('select[name="lesson[course_id]"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);
function changeEventHandler(event) {
    code = event.target.value;
    if($.inArray(code,number) >= 0) {
      $(".vimeo").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".vimeo").show();
    }
}

</script>
```

I would like to check if the event target value is included in the "number array". If it is, I want to hide the div or vice versa.

Comment: Is variable `number` an array?

Comment: Try `if (number.includes(code)) {...} else {...}`. Also `@courses_ids` or something like that instead of `@new_number` for `@number.ids` is more clear(`code` => `selectedCourseId` too)

Comment: @Satpal yhh, number is an array

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Leo . I would change the variable names. but in the meantime, the solution did not work

Comment: share output of `console.log(number)` and `console.log(typeof number)`

Comment: @satpal console.log gives me the ids in what looks like an array. console.log(typeof) says it is an "object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  var courcesIds = <%= @new_number %>;
  $('select[name="lesson[course_id]"]').change(function(){
    if (courcesIds.includes(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
      $(".vimeo").css("display", "none");
      // $(".vimeo").hide();
    }
    else {
      $(".vimeo").css("display", "block");
      // $(".vimeo").show();
    }
  })
<script>
```

Comment: it does not work. when i type console.log(typeof courcesIds), it says it is an object and not an array. I am a bit confused by that

Comment: @HakeemBaba, `typeof [1, 2, 3] #=> 'object'`. It is normal. Use `Array.isArray(courcesIds) ` when want check it is an array or not. There is some error? Can you provide the context of your code snippet(with .vimeo block)?

Comment: this is the vimeo block code                                                                              
    <div class="vimeo">
      <%= f.input :video, label: t(".vimeo_link_to_video") %>
    </div>

Comment: I am rendering it via html. Here is the select code                                           
<%= f.association :course, collection: current_academy.courses.collect { |u| [u.title, u.id] }, prompt: t("select") %>

Comment: `f.association` generate `select` that includes all options with a string value. So, `[int, int, int].includes(string)` always `false`